# Count series of events within a 30 days period

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with Python and Pandas. I have a dataframe looking like below:

```
codename    date         
AAA         13-03-2015   
AAB         20-02-2015   
AAB         15-04-2015  
AAB         20-04-2015  
AAB         21-04-2015  
AAB         21-05-2015
```

I'm looking for help with calculating the series of events within a 30 day period. I have tried to illustrate what I'm hoping to achieve in the sheet below:

```
codename    date         daysBetween  series
AAA         13-03-2015   NaN          1
AAB         20-02-2015   NaN          1    
AAB         15-04-2015   54           1
AAB         20-04-2015   5            0
AAB         21-04-2015   6            0 
AAB         21-05-2015   36           1
```

If more than 30 days has passed from cell 1 (20-02-2015) to cell (15-04-2015), then count the days between (54 days) and put result in `daysBetween` and put 1 into `series`.

If not more than 30 days has passed between two cells, count the days and input 0 in series.

The dates should compare to the last date where series were 1.

---

I've managed to sort by codename and by date:

```
import pandas as pd

file = pd.read_excel('sample.xlsx')

sortedData = file.sort_values(by=['codename', 'date'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need compare values by [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.gt.html) and cast to integers by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) for `True/False` to `1/0` mapping:

```
#convert column to datetimes
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d-%m-%Y')
#sorting
df = df.sort_values(by=['codename', 'date'])
#get difference between first value of group
df['daysBetween'] = df['date'].sub(df.groupby('codename')['date'].transform('first')).dt.days
#compare by gt (>) and cast to int
df['series'] = df['daysBetween'].gt(30).astype(int)
print (df)
  codename       date  daysBetween  series
0      AAA 2015-03-13            0       0
1      AAB 2015-02-20            0       0
2      AAB 2015-04-15           54       1
3      AAB 2015-04-20           59       1
4      AAB 2015-04-21           60       1
5      AAB 2015-05-21           90       1
```

If need difference between values:

```
df['daysBetween'] = df.groupby('codename')['date'].diff().dt.days
df['series'] = df['daysBetween'].gt(30).astype(int)
print (df)
  codename       date  daysBetween  series
0      AAA 2015-03-13          NaN       0
1      AAB 2015-02-20          NaN       0
2      AAB 2015-04-15         54.0       1
3      AAB 2015-04-20          5.0       0
4      AAB 2015-04-21          1.0       0
5      AAB 2015-05-21         30.0       0
```